# Why does Umbraco run App_Data\Temp\Razor\inline-xxxx.cshtml logout control after my login?

Tags: razor, forms-authentication, umbraco, appdata

My Umbraco website has 2 member types. I made a custom login form which checks credentials and authenticates members. Here is my Umbraco razor control code that does that:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines;

@{
    if (Request.HttpMethod.ToLower() == "post")
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("username") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty("password"))
        {
            string username = Request["username"];
            string password = Request["password"];
            var isValid = Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
            if (isValid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);

                //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
                Response.Redirect(new DynamicNode(2431).Url, true);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For one of the member types authentication works just fine. For other, after the member is authenticated, Umbraco runs script \App_Data\TEMP\Razor\inline-6ff314cb99b9da6a178f3b2d31bc709e.cshtml. That script has following code:

```
@{
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        // Drop all the information held in the session
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();

        // clear authentication cookie
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        // clear session cookie
        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

        // Redirect the user to the login page
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
  }
```

Off course, after this script is triggered my member is logged out. Why is this script triggered and how can I stop it?

My current Umbraco version is 4.11.3. I think it's important to mention that it used to be 4.7.0 and I upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't in Umbraco or in Membership. It was related to my custom member objects.